# why am I failing to push_back objects into c++ multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, runtime, stdvector

so I'm learning c++, and coding game of life for practice.
I'm confused about vectors, and multidimensional vectors.

```
class TABLE{
     public:
     int height;
     int width;
     vector<vector<CELL>> matrix_A; 
     vector<vector<CELL>> matrix_B;
     bool current_matrix_is_a = true;
     TABLE(int h,int w){
          this->height=h;
          this->width=w;
          for (int y = 0; y < this->height; y++)
               {
               for (int x = 0; x < this->width; x++)
                    {
                    matrix_A[y].push_back(CELL(x,y));
                    matrix_B[y].push_back(CELL(x,y));     
               }
          }
     }
}
```

what this code is trying to do is make a pair of 2d vectors, and fill each row will a cell object instantiated with the x,y of where it is in the matrix.
the code compiles fine, however the .exe crashes - when it reaches the push_back method.
am I missing something basic with the syntax?

Comment: Try replacing `matrix_A[y].push_back(CELL(x,y));` with `matrix_A.at(y).push_back(CELL(x,y));`.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. In particular, show the code that uses this class.

Answer (score 1):

Lets reduce this to a really simple example:

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        v[y].push_back(make_some_int());
```

Lets do a little experiment, we can print out the size of the outside vector
:

```
 std::Cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

What do we get? `0`! The size is 0, so when we do this for the first round:

```
v[y].push_back ...
```

what are we pushing back into? There is no element at index `y` that exists. So we need to make it:

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {
    vector<int> tmp; // Our tmp 1d vector
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        tmp.push_back(make_some_int()); // This will work
    }
    v.emplace_back(std::move(tmp)); // Now we push back our 2d part. 
                // (std::move is a little c+++11 trick, feel free to google it.)
```

Now it will work!

Answer (score 0):

`matrix_A[y]` refers to a non-existent element since `matrix_A` is empty.  Likewise `matrix_B[y]`.

The easiest solution is probably to resize these vectors before entering the loop.  That creates the elements you need:

```
matrixA.resize (this->height);
matrixB.resize (this->height);
for (int y = 0; y < this->height; y++)
...
```

You don't need to specify `this->` BTW, although it is harmless to do so.